# Can I get a manual focus lens for my Canon PowerShot camera?

Tags: lens, canon, manual-focus, powershot

I have recently bought myself a camera, a Canon PowerShot SX530, and I noticed that the focus on this camera is difficult to adjust and clarify. I am looking to buy a low priced manual focus lens, I saw a BRIGHTIN STAR 35mm F1.7 Ultra Wide Manual Focus Lens on Amazon. My question is 1) if this focus lens is of good quality and 2) if this lens is compatible with my current camera. I am new to photography and don't have a lot of knowledge about the rules and regulations. Thank you for anyone who answers this question for me.

Comment: On the orher hand, buying an eos-m camera that fits that lens you where considering would give you excelent focus capability, the m50 with the kit lens being an option that has got great reviews. In other words, if you move to an interchangable lens camera things like focusing systems often have more options, so if you feel limited by your gear that might be a good upgrade.

Comment: Ok thank you mattdm, I will definitely be looking into an eos-m camera. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you're taking votes, I vote for FujiFilm camera with X-Trans sensor, like X-T20.

Answer (score 6):

That lens is listed as compatible with Canon EOS-M cameras, which are interchangable lens cameras. The PowerShot line of cameras does not have an interchangable lens. So, no, it's not compatible with your SX530.

I can't speak to the quality of the lens, but the lack of any reviews on Amazon says something... As does the fact that a simple Google search for "Brightin Star" shows ... nothing.

Comment: Yes, the lack of reviews on Amazon did concern me. Thank you for the clarification and answer!

Answer (score 5):

- **Your camera (PowerShot SX###) cannot use other lenses**, *unless* you consider screw-on converter lenses. I expect most here would not consider such "lenses" to be "real" lenses. Conversion lenses would also exacerbate whatever problems you're having with your current lens.
- If you're still within the return window, consider returning the PowerShot so you can **get a mirrorless camera** instead. Previous-generation models can be very inexpensive and should still perform better than the PowerShot.

  Why not a DSLR? It's difficult to adapt arbitrary lenses to DSLRs. If you want to be able to use most manual-focus lenses you encounter, you pretty much need a mirrorless camera.
- **The Brightin Star lens looks like a rebranded Neewer lens.** If so... Ignore all the glowing reviews of various Chinese-made lenses. I don't know, and don't want, whatever those reviewers are smoking. Those lenses' **contrast is poor**; they're **difficult to focus**, and they **suffer from horrible veiling glare**.

  You're likely to get a much better lens at a lower cost by searching for an old 35mm f/2.8 on auction. Even a no-name, generic brand would do. – But you need to get a mirrorless camera first.

  Here's an image taken with a Kamero (Mitake) 35mm f/2.8 @ F8 (on a FujiFilm X-T20, Provia, unedited JPEG). The cheesy brand name just screams low quality, but the lens itself is nothing to scoff at. It's sharp with nice colors and contrast, and it's resistant to veiling glare.

  [image: Kamero 35mm f/2.8 @ F5.6]

Comment: Okay, thank you... I wasn't sure if my camera was able to use other lenses. I am glad that I received answers, I would rather know about complications about the lens before buying it rather than after. Thank you for your advice and answer!

Answer (score 4):

The [Canon PowerShot SX530](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/products/details/cameras/point-and-shoot/long-zoom-cameras/powershot-sx530-hs) is **not** an interchangeable lens camera. You cannot buy other lenses for it.

While I have no experience with the Brightin Star lens you ask about, I do not expect it to be a great one.

Comment: Yes, I suspected the same results with the Brightin Star. Thank you for your answer!